# Polymorphism methods or classes

Tags: oop, polymorphism

I would like to know more about polymorphism in oop has a subject not related to any particular languages(c++, java, python).
I would like to learn and understand Polymorphism in it's true form (leaving the idoms of the languages aside).

Background:
I was asked in a phone interview to explain Polymorphism?
My answer: Polymorphism has to do with methods and is achieved by overloading(static binding) and overriding(dynamic binding). Explained the diff between overloading and overriding

The interviewer's response was that I was wrong and Polymorphism has to do with classes not methods. I strongly disagree but this guy is Head of Tech and a grad from Columbia with BS and MS in Computer Science(about 15-20 years of experience) where as I am from a state college with a B.S in Computer Science(< 4 years of experience)

Comment: Have you tried searching existing questions? I am sure they already cover this? That said, *Polymorphism* is a broad concept but the most important aspect of *Polymorphic* object oriented code is that it allows an object to belong to more than one type.

Comment: I understand that polymorphism 'allows an object to belong to more than one type.' All that is attained by writing polymorphic methods(What is a class without any methods defined(I mean a blank class)). So my point is polymorphism is achieved by writing polymorphic  methods.

Comment: @linuxWiz98 That's where you seem to go wrong. *Polymorphic* substitutions are not achieved through overriding. *Polymorphic* substitutions are achieved through *Inheritance* (class extension). There is no need to *override* a method in the subclass to take advantage of *Polymorphism*. If `A` is a class that has a `doSomething` method and `B extends A`, then a reference of type `A` can refer to both an `A`  and `B` instance without a mandate to *override* `doSomething` in `B`. Now if we talk about runtime polymorphism, that is where you could really start talking about overriding methods.

Comment: I want to address both method overloading(static binding) and method overriding(dynamic binding) the two ways we can achieve polymorphism in any OOP language. For a class to become polymorphic there is no special delecaration(polymorphic class A(object) that makes in polymorphic). My point is polymorphism is achieved by writing polymorphic methods that help change a class's behavior based on the signature of the method being invoked(I think people just stop at polymorphism is how classes change their behavior and then they think it has to do with classes only, they forget how it is achieved).

Comment: I think we write polymorphic methods not polymorphic classes(classes are nothing but containers with groups of attrs(data fields, methods) that are generic(base classes) and specfic(child classes))

Comment: I am looking for a proper answer that can help with my next interview, but I also want the answer to be complete

Comment: I explained very clearly in my comment that *Polymorphism* is achieved through *Inheritance* and *overriding* is not a mandate. I leave it to you :). Good luck.

Comment: Poly = many, Morph = shape. It has nothing to do with if the methods of the underlying forms are virtual or overloaded or overridden. `public abstract class Vehicle { public int Wheels; public Vehicle(int w) { Wheels = w; } } public class Bicycle : Vehicle { public Bicycle() : base(2) { } } public class Car : Vehicle { public Car() : base(4) { } } public class Truck : Vehicle { public Truck() : base(18) { } }` An instance of Vehicle can be assigned an object of Car or Truck and its Wheels field will return based on the actual type

Comment: The essence of the polymorpism is how objects behave, not how you define the methods and I wouldn't talk about static or dynamic binding and instead about the fact that seemingly the same entity can behave differently depending on what actual type it has (still having the same external interface, so whoever uses it can't actually tell the difference).

Comment: Also, [there are different types of polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). In general, this looks like a question where you can have a debate. If I asked such a question during the interview, I would judge more on how you are making the discussion rather than on the actual answer (as far as I see that you have general understanding of what we are talking about).

Comment: @BorisSerebrov I found this https://anampiu.github.io/blog/OOP-principles/ I do understand the point that yes a debate can happen on this topic. I see and understand Poly = many, Morph = shape but you are declaring methods with same name but with different signatures(params) not classes(maybe templates in c++). The objects behave differently based on the methods. I say methods are polymorphic not classes/objects. Maybe I am talking about how it can be achieved and what it is. But I think the interviewer wanted the answer of what is polymorphism

Comment: `you are declaring methods with same name but with different signatures(params) not classes(maybe templates in c++)` - you are talking about first two types mentioned in wikipedia article - [ad hoc polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Ad_hoc_polymorphism) and [parametric ploymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Parametric_polymorphism). While most commonly we are referring to the third type, [subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Subtyping) which is about classes/objects.

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly, when we talk about OOP, the term `polymorphism` is used to describe objects behavior when we use the inheritance, so we can use objects of the subtypes as if there were objects of the base class (these objects of the subtypes become polymorphic, they have two forms - own type and base class type).

For example if we have a hierarchy of objects representing integer and real numbers where we have base `Number` class:

```
         Number
        /     \
       /       \
      /         \
  Integer      Real
```

Each class defines own set of operations, for example `add` and `multiply`. Now, we can use an `object` of type `Integer` both as an `Integer` and as a `Number` (same for `Real` and `Complex`) - so this object is polymorphic, it can represent two types (classes):

```
n1 = Integer(...)
n2 = Integer(...)
r  = Real(...)

// Now we can have a function that takes advantage of the
// polymorphic behavior, notice that it takes `Number` as
// argument types, so it doesn't know what are actual types

function f(x: Number, y: Number) {
    // here we don't know if x and y are integer or real
    return x.multiply(x).add(y);  // x*x + y
}

Number result1 = f(n1, n2)  // here we also don't know the specific
Number result2 = f(n2, r)   // type of the result
```

That's the point of the `subtype polymorphism`, now we can define more number subtypes (for example, a type for real numbers with better floating-point precision, but slower processing). At the same time the `f` function will stay exactly as it is, because it doesn't depend on specific types.

Note that `polymorphism` can also be used to describe how functions behave, for example, when we declare the function with same name but different parameters and the compiler chooses which implementation to use in specific situations (example from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism)):

```
function Add(x, y : Integer) : Integer;
begin
    Add := x + y
end;

function Add(s, t : String) : String;
begin
    Add := Concat(s, t)
end;

begin
    Writeln(Add(1, 2));                   (* Prints "3"             *)
    Writeln(Add('Hello, ', 'World!'));    (* Prints "Hello, World!" *)
end.
```

Also `polymorphism` [can be used to describe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Parametric_polymorphism) generic functions / classes (templates).